# Meaning of a commuting maps?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

What is *commuting* and *commuting maps* in mathematics? Did they different with commutative group?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably (and it is difficult to be 100% sure without further context), maps $f:A\rightarrow A$ and $g:A\rightarrow A$ are said to be commute if

$$f\circ g=g\circ f\Leftrightarrow f(g(a))=g(f(a)),$$
for all $a\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion (and I have to agree with Jp McCarthy: without more context, we cannot be certain what you mean), when someone says that maps $f,g$ commute whenever $f\circ g=g\circ f$.

However, an alternative meaning might be that they make a particular diagram commute. For example, if $f_{ab}:A\to B$, $f_{bd}:B\to D$, $f_{ac}:A\to C$, and $f_{cd}:C\to D$, then the diagram formed by them is said to commute when $f_{bd}\circ f_{ab}=f_{cd}\circ f_{ac}$. This, in some sense, generalizes the above idea of commuting maps.